# Make the objects' size of a GUI adapt to window

Tags: qt, user-interface, pyqt

I created a GUI with Qt5 but I will like the objects to be always contained in the window. When I change the size of the window (with the mouse), the objects dont resize themselves and therefore are hidden by the window.

Basically, I will like my GUI to act like a Web Page for example.

I think I have to use the Layout properties to do that but I dont seem to find it in Qt (in the QBBoxLayout or QWidget ?). I will like to change this in Qt and not in my PyQt script if possible.

Comment: Have a look here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/examples-layouts.html

Comment: See: [Using Layouts in Qt Designer](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/designer-layouts.html).

Comment: Thank you, interesting documents but i still can't figure out how to do it. I have a Layout on the GUI but it doesn't stop the elements being hidden when the window is minimize..

Answer (score 1):

Have you set the layout of the window ?

Normally you should have a code similar to this one

```
dialog = QDialog()
verticalLayout = QVBoxLayout()
label1 = QLabel("first")
label2 = QLabel("second")
verticalLayout.addWidget(label1)
verticalLayout.addWidget(label2)
dialog.setLayout(verticalLayout)
```

if you are creating the gui writing the necessary the code yourself.

If you are creating the gui with the designer, probably you have not applied a layout to your window.

Comment: I have a Vertical Layout that captures all the Widgets & Objects i've created. But it doesn't seem to do what i would like. When i minimize the window of the GUI, the objects are just hidden, they dont reposition themselves and resize themselves.
I'm sure this must no be difficult to do, but i can't find out how. The Layout, if i understant, are just to position the objects

Comment: The way you are describing the problem, seems that you don't set the layout of the window, but without looking at the code, I cannot be sure. Is it possible to view some code ?

Comment: self.layoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralWidget)
self.layoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 2, 2))
self.layoutWidget.setObjectName("layoutWidget")
self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.layoutWidget)        self.verticalLayout.setSizeConstraint(QtWidgets.QLayout.SetDefaultConstraint)
 self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
 self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
Interface.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)

These are the bits of code where layout is mentionned..

(I dont know how to put it in 'code' mode ..)